# Mysterious Gap Vertically Between Block Elements

Tags: html, css, position, margin, padding

[SOLVED] I answered my own question, but Stack Overflow will not allow me to set my own post as the answer for 2 days. Thanks! :)

How do I get rid of the small gap between these two block elements? I have tried setting the white space to none, and all the margins/padding to 0. When I inspect it with Google Chrome Inspector Tool, I cannot find what seems to be causing the gap. How is it there?

This does not have to do with the inline-block gap that everyone else seems to have since they are not inline elements. I have also tried changing the position on the child element, but that did not work either.

Does this issue have to do with that "clear fix" thing? Should I use that? I am an extremely beginner programmer so maybe I am overlooking this simple problem, but I feel that I have tried everything.

[NOTE]: I have also reset the css, so it is not coming from the browser's stylesheet.

Here is a link to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/vKrbaB).

```css
.mobile-navigation {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
}
.open {
  max-height: 500px;
}
.mobile-navigation li,
.mobile-navigation a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: 'Special Elite';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mobile-navigation a {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 8em;
  padding-left: 8em;
}
.mobile-navigation li {
  padding: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.mobile-navigation a:active,
.mobile-navigation li.current-menu-item > a,
.mobile-navigation li.current-page-parent > a,
.mobile-navigation li.current_page_parent > a,
.mobile-navigation li.current-page-ancestor > a,
.mobile-navigation li.current-menu-parent > a,
.mobile-navigation li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
.mobile-navigation a:hover {
  color: tan !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
.mobile-navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}
mobile-navigation li.current-menu-item > ul.sub-menu,
.mobile-navigation li.current-menu-item li.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu,
.mobile-navigation li.current-page-ancestor > ul.sub-menu {
  display: block !important;
}
/* Hamburger */

.hamburger {
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mobile-header .meta {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: black;
}
.mobile-header img {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.mobile-header .site-branding {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hamburger-line {
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  width: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.hamburger-line:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-header">

  <div class="meta">

    <div href="#" class="hamburger">
      <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
      <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
      <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
    </div>


    <img src="www.example.com/image" />

  </div>

  <div class="mobile-navigation open">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/blog/">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/about/">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/contact/">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it's not though :P View my answer.

Comment: The space is caused because your element is an inline-block. Not a block.

Comment: Not true. It was caused by the default `vertical-align: baseline`. Your `line-height: 0` just collapses the entire line so `vertical-align` no longer has distinguishable effects. Just like nuking Earth to kill a mosquito, but yes, it works. Anyways, did you even read the duplicate? Your `line-height: 0` is already there.

Comment: My bad. I am an extremely beginner programmer. I see what you mean, and what Memo was explaining below. Great metaphor.

Comment: Also, changing vertical align on both of the elements seemed to have no effect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding line-height: 0; to mobile-header fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.meta` **is** set to `inline-box` and that's the problem.

set it to `block` and div it some height and you should be set. If you want get rid of all the white space, you'll also need to set `margin-top: 0;` on `.mobile-navigation > ul`

Comment: I don't think it is, because I fixed the issue by changing the line height of the entire header.

Comment: look at your code: `.mobile-header .meta { display: inline-block; ...`

Comment: The issue is already fixed, you can view the codepen for the fix if you'd like. This was not the problem. :P

Comment: changing the line height is a work around, not a fix. But if that's good enough for you, it's all good. :)

Comment: But how would the meta be causing this? Any help for a real fix is greatly appreciated. :)